Difference between Fundamental and Universal Property
What is the difference between a fundamental property and a universal property?? Is charge a fundamental property or universal property of matter??

It would be interesting to post this question in the physics forum too.

A fundamental property is one which cannot be explained by, or grounded in other properties. Thus fundamental properties are the basic properties in nature; charge is one of them. These fundamental properties act like building blocks when we describe the laws of nature. They are like a vocabulary used in the description of these laws.
Universals on the other hand are mathematical constructs. So, to your question of whether a fundamental is a universal too, the answer depends (partially) on whether you believe that the fundamental properties are in fact concrete physical properties or intellectual/abstract constructs of ours; or in other words whether the laws of physics are the driving forces of nature, or a construct of ours that models the behaviour of nature; or in other words whether the laws are governing a transition from one state to another, or are a way of approaching/modelling the differentiation from one state to another.
This philosophical problem is not solved yet. The mainstream view is the first one, I go with the second one.
A complete answer requires more analysis, this is only an introduction.
